# Can google speech API convert text to speech?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-speech-api

I used Google speech API ti successfully convert speech to text using following code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os

#obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Google Cloud Speech
GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS = r"""{KEY}
"""
# INSERT THE CONTENTS OF THE GOOGLE CLOUD SPEECH JSON CREDENTIALS FILE HERE
try:
    speechOutput = (r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, credentials_json=GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS, language="si-LK"))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    speechOutput = ("Google Cloud Speech could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    speechOutput = ("Could not request results from Google Cloud Speech service; {0}".format(e))
print(speechOutput)
```

I want to know if i can convert text to speech using the same API? If not what API to use and the sample python code for that. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you'll need to use the new [Text-to-Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/) which is in Beta as of now. You can find a [Python quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) in the Client Library section of the docs. The sample is part of the [python-docs-sample repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/texttospeech/cloud-client/synthesize_text.py). Adding the relevant part of the example here for better visibility:

```
def synthesize_text(text):
    """Synthesizes speech from the input string of text."""
    from google.cloud import texttospeech
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

    input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)

    # Note: the voice can also be specified by name.
    # Names of voices can be retrieved with client.list_voices().
    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code='en-US',
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

    response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)

    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

*Update: rate and pitch configuration*

You can enclose the text elements in a `<prosody>` tag to modify the `rate`and `pitch`. For example:

```
<prosody rate="slow" pitch="-2st">Can you hear me now?</prosody>
```

The possible values for those follow the W3 specifications which can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.2.4). The [SSML docs](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml) for Text-to-Speech API detail this and they also provide some samples.

Also, you can control the general audio playback rate with the `speed` option in `<audio>`, which currently accepts values from 50 to 200% (in 1% increments).

Comment: Hi @Guillem, can you tell me the possible values for Speed & Pitch in this api? please!